# How can I deploy aqueduct application to web hosting plan using cpanel?

Tags: flutter, dart, aqueduct

HI im very new to back end and Im learning aqueduct since I know dart programming. My question is how can I deploy the aqueduct to my webserver?  I have a hosting plan to a2hosting which Im currently using for my wordpress site and I wonder if I can deploy my dart server to cpanel so I can use them as a backend to my flutter app? Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on many factors.

Generally I'd say "no can do".

Get a VPS and host it there.

It depends on if your cpanel hoster has access via ssh enabled, which they usually don't. But even then I'm confident the hoster won't allow long running apps on his shared hosting server.

- Dart has to be installed on the host, which is usually not the case on shared hosting servers
- You need some kind of external oauth2 service
- You need a postgresql database server, which cpanel provides but your hoster might not

[Aqueduct official deployment guides](https://aqueduct.io/docs/deploy/) are found on the their official site.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot install dart sdk on a2hosting shared hosting plan. Even if they give you SSH access, you will not have enough permission to install DART SDK. But you can deploy you app on heroku for free. You will get enough resources to run your app. You can upgrade your plan later according to your needs.

Check  the heroku documention to deploy aqueduct app

[Deploying an Aqueduct Application on Heroku](https://aqueduct.io/docs/deploy/deploy_heroku/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I actually have to give the bounty to the 1st answer since you do have same answer. I was hoping its possible but I think I have to use other hosting. Thanks again